# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : create authorization policy dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

After the user login I go to the database and return the roles that are available for objects (textbox, buttons) for the entire application.

With those `Object-Roles` I want to create an authorization policy that will be used by the User to have or NOT Have access to that object.

As far as I know and my experience, the policy is set in `program.cs`.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminAccess", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
}
```

But in this case, I have to do it dynamically somewhere else, after `program.cs` is loaded.

What is the best approach to generate these policies?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you could only get services from Servicecollection (the default container) after builded,modify ,delete or add services are not allowed,may be you could try to replace the default container

Answer (score 1):

An authorization handler is responsible for the evaluation of a requirement's properties. Then you can evaluates the requirements against a provided AuthorizationHandlerContext to determine if access is allowed.

Then it will look like this code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ThePolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add( new ThePolicyRequirement() ));
});

services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyPolicyAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Then you can

```
public class MyPolicyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyPolicyRequirement>
{
  readonly AppDbContext _context;


public MyPolicyAuthorizationHandler(DbContext c)
{
    _context = c;
   
}

protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyPolicyRequirement requirement)
{
    // Check context.User and context.Resource against db
     ....
    if (_context.PolicyRequirements.FirstOrDefault(....) && context.User.HasClaim("Some claim"))
     {
        
        context.Succeed(requirement);
     }

    return Task.CompletedTask;   
    ....
   }               
  }
}

public class MyPolicyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for more information about authorization handler and requirements.